# Change cell in datagridview with databindings of SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

1. In SQL Server, I created a dynamic SQL stored procedure to query for the production record and pivoted in each month
2. In ASP.net using VB.net, I have a page with a `DataGrid` to display the query results dynamically using the `DataBound` method
3. I have a textbox to change the value of specific cell in the `DataGridView` like the production order quantity

Problem: when I assigned a value from textbox to the cell of datagridview, there is no change at all.

It just refreshed and get the value of the SQL query from the stored procedure. It always invokes the `DataBound` method of the `DataGrid`.

Questions: what is the technique so that I can assign the value to cell of `DataGridView` which is has data binding to the dynamic SQL Server stored procedure? The thing here is I want to save the changes in the `DataGrid` to another `Table` as the transnational.

Here is aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="GeneratePlan.aspx.vb" Inherits="GeneratePlan" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="cc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 55px;
        }
        .style2
        {
            width: 7px;
        }
        </style>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <div>
      <table width="100%">          
            <tr  >

                <td style="text-align: right;" >
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save Plan" CssClass="button" /><asp:Button ID="btnExit" runat="server" Text="Exit" CssClass="button"  />
                 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td    class="tdHeaderSubSection">
                <asp:Label ID="lblReq" runat="server" Text=">> Generate Plan"></asp:Label>
              </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
 </div>
 <div>
    <table width ="100%">
      <tr>
            <td class="style1">
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="BU"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="style2">::</td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBU" CssClass="Data" runat="server" Height="16px" 
                    Width="130px">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnGenerate" CssClass="button" runat="server" Text="Generate" />

                <asp:Button ID="btnMove" CssClass="button" runat="server" 
                    Text="Move MC#" />

                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan ="3"> <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                            </asp:ScriptManager> </td>
        </tr>


    </table>    
 </div>

 <div id ="planDtl">
          <asp:GridView ID="grdPlanDtl"  AutoGenerateColumns = "False" 
        runat="server" Font-Size="10px">      

     </asp:GridView>

 </div>

  <div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is the vb.net code:

```
Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdPlanDtl.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim ItemCode As New Label()
            ItemCode.ID = "ItemCode"
            ItemCode.Text = TryCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView).Row("ItemCode").ToString()
            e.Row.Cells(1).Controls.Add(ItemCode)

            ItemCode.Width = 100
            Dim Description As New Label()
            Description.ID = "Description"
            Description.Text = TryCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView).Row("Description").ToString()
            e.Row.Cells(2).Controls.Add(Description)
            Description.Width = 200
            Dim WH As New Label()
            WH.ID = "WH"
            WH.Text = TryCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView).Row("WH").ToString()
            e.Row.Cells(3).Controls.Add(WH)
            e.Row.Cells(3).HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center


            WH.Width = 10
            Dim Customer As New Label()
            Customer.ID = "Customer"
            Customer.Text = TryCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView).Row("CustName").ToString()
            e.Row.Cells(4).Controls.Add(Customer)
            Customer.Width = 150

            Dim ST As New Label()
            ST.ID = "ST"
            ST.Text = FormatNumber(TryCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView).Row("Std.Time").ToString(), 2)
            e.Row.Cells(5).Controls.Add(ST)
            e.Row.Cells(5).HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right
            ST.Width = 30


            Dim TON As New Label()
            TON.ID = "TON"
            TON.Text = TryCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView).Row("Tonnage").ToString()
            e.Row.Cells(6).Controls.Add(TON)
            e.Row.Cells(6).HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right
            TON.Width = 40


            Dim MachineNo As New Label()
            MachineNo.ID = "MachineNo"
            MachineNo.Text = TryCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView).Row("MachineNo").ToString()
            e.Row.Cells(7).Controls.Add(MachineNo)
            MachineNo.Width = 50



            Dim TRP As New Label()
            TRP.ID = "TRP"
            TRP.Text = TryCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView).Row("TRP").ToString()
            e.Row.Cells(10).Controls.Add(TRP)
            TRP.Width = 50




            Dim FixedMachine As New Label()
            Dim strFix As String
            FixedMachine.ID = "FixedMachine"
            FixedMachine.Text = TryCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView).Row("FixedMachine").ToString()
            e.Row.Cells(8).Controls.Add(FixedMachine)
            FixedMachine.Width = 50

            Dim chkSel As New CheckBox
            chkSel.ID = "Move"
            chkSel.Checked = False
            e.Row.Cells(0).Controls.Add(chkSel)
            Dim row As GridViewRow = TryCast(FixedMachine.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
            strFix = TryCast(row.FindControl("FixedMachine"), Label).Text
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(strFix) Then
                chkSel.Enabled = True
            Else
                chkSel.Enabled = True
                ' chkSel.Enabled = False
            End If

            '    AddGrdColumn("AvailableTime", "Available Time", "Lable")

            'getsum

            strGrpMC = TON.Text & MachineNo.Text
            For i As Integer = 0 To iLoopMonth - 1

                Dim ShpOrd As New Label()
                Dim ShpOrdBckOrd As New TextBox()
                Dim PlanM1 As New TextBox()
                Dim ActualM1 As New TextBox()
                Dim BackOrder As New Label()
                Dim NeedHr As New Label()
                ShpOrd.ID = "ShpOrd"
                ShpOrd.Text = TryCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView).Row(arrayMonth(i)).ToString()
                e.Row.Cells(11 + (9 * i) + i).Controls.Add(ShpOrd)

                ShpOrd.Width = 50

                ShpOrdBckOrd.ID = "ShpOrdBckOrd"
                ShpOrdBckOrd.Text = ShpOrd.Text
                e.Row.Cells(12 + (9 * i) + i).Controls.Add(ShpOrdBckOrd)
                ShpOrdBckOrd.Width = 50

                PlanM1.ID = "PlanM1"
                PlanM1.Text = ""
                e.Row.Cells(13 + (9 * i) + i).Controls.Add(PlanM1)
                PlanM1.Width = 50

                ActualM1.ID = "ActualM1"
                ActualM1.Text = ""
                ActualM1.AutoPostBack = True
                AddHandler ActualM1.TextChanged, AddressOf txtAcutal_TextChanged
                e.Row.Cells(14 + (9 * i) + i).Controls.Add(ActualM1)
                ActualM1.Width = 50

                BackOrder.ID = "BackOrder"
                BackOrder.Text = ""
                BackOrder.Text = GetBackOrder(ShpOrdBckOrd.Text, ActualM1.Text)
                e.Row.Cells(15 + (9 * i) + i).Controls.Add(BackOrder)
                BackOrder.Width = 50

                NeedHr.ID = "NeedHr"
                NeedHr.Text = GetNeedHr(ShpOrd.Text, PlanM1.Text, ST.Text, TRP.Text)
                e.Row.Cells(16 + (9 * i) + i).Controls.Add(NeedHr)
                NeedHr.Width = 50
                ' summary
                '  MsgBox("strGrpMC  : " & strGrpMC)
                '  MsgBox("strTmpGrpMC  : " & strTmpGrpMC)
                strGrpMC = TON.Text & "-" & MachineNo.Text
                If strGrpMC <> strTmpGrpMC Then
                    LodTmeTT = 0
                    BalTmeTT = 0
                    strTmpGrpMC = strGrpMC
                    strGrpMC = TON.Text & "-" & MachineNo.Text
                    LodTmeTT = LodTmeTT + Convert.ToDouble(ChkNull(GetNeedHr(ShpOrd.Text, PlanM1.Text, ST.Text, TRP.Text), 0))
                Else
                    strTmpGrpMC = strGrpMC
                    strGrpMC = TON.Text & "-" & MachineNo.Text
                    LodTmeTT = LodTmeTT + Convert.ToDouble(ChkNull(GetNeedHr(ShpOrd.Text, PlanM1.Text, ST.Text, TRP.Text), 0))
                End If
                '("#,##0.00")

                Dim AvailableTime As New TextBox()
                AvailableTime.ID = "AvailableTime"
                AvailableTime.Text = TryCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView).Row("AvailableTime").ToString()

                e.Row.Cells(18 + (9 * i) + i).Controls.Add(AvailableTime)
                AvailableTime.Width = 50


                Dim Loading As New Label()
                Loading.ID = "Loading"
                Loading.Text = LodTmeTT
                e.Row.Cells(17 + (9 * i) + i).Controls.Add(Loading)

                Loading.Width = 50
                Loading.Text = LodTmeTT

                Dim balTme As New Label()
                balTme.ID = "balTme"
                balTme.Text = GetBalTime(AvailableTime.Text, Loading.Text)
                e.Row.Cells(19 + (9 * i) + i).Controls.Add(balTme)
                balTme.Width = 50



                Dim RatioTme As New Label()
                RatioTme.ID = "RatioTme"
                RatioTme.Text = GetLoadRatioTime(Loading.Text, AvailableTime.Text)
                e.Row.Cells(20 + (9 * i) + i).Controls.Add(RatioTme)
                RatioTme.Width = 50
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: its a basic task, you have to read articles about how to update a record of database...

Comment: Can you post your aspx & vb page code here?

Comment: Hi Rajan, above I edited and included your request.